# SWTException: Invalid thread access

Tags: java, concurrency, swt, wizard, eclipse-plugin

I work on a wizard for creation of a java project and get a invalid thread access exception if I run it in the empty workspace for the first time. I try to implement my wizard similar to `JavaProjectWizard`, but I don't need the second page, so I try to perform finish from the first page and to initialize the second page in advance:

```java
import org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewJavaProjectWizardPageTwo;
import org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard;
import org.eclipse.ui.INewWizard;

public class SomeNewWizard
    extends Wizard
    implements INewWizard {

    private SomeWizardPageTwo javaWizardPageTwo;

    @Override
    public void addPages() {
            if (javaWizardPageTwo == null)
                    someWizardPageTwo = new SomeWizardPageTwo(newSeeAppWizardPageOne);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performFinish() {
/*line 109*/someWizardPageTwo .createProvisonalProject();
            final IWorkspaceRunnable op = new IWorkspaceRunnable() {
                    public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor)
                            throws CoreException, OperationCanceledException {
                            try {
                                    someWizardPageTwo.performFinish(new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, 1));
                            }
                            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    throw new OperationCanceledException(e.getMessage());
                            }
                            finally {
                                    monitor.done();
                            }
                    }
            };
            try {
                    rule = null;
                    Job job = Job.getJobManager().currentJob();
                    if (job != null)
                            rule = job.getRule();
                    IRunnableWithProgress runnable = new IRunnableWithProgress() {
                            @Override
                            public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor)
                                    throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
                                    try {
                                            JavaCore.run(op, rule, monitor);
                                    }
                                    catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
                                            throw new InterruptedException(e.getMessage());
                                    }
                                    catch (CoreException e) {
                                            throw new InvocationTargetException(e);
                                    }
                            }
                    };
                    getContainer().run(true, true, runnable);
            }
            catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    handleFinishException(getShell(), e);
                    return false;
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
    }

public class SomeWizardPageTwo
    extends NewJavaProjectWizardPageTwo
{

    private NewJavaProjectWizardPageOne mainPage;


    public SomeWizardPageTwo(NewJavaProjectWizardPageOne mainPage)
    {
        super(mainPage);
        this.mainPage = mainPage;
    }


    @Override
    public IProject createProvisonalProject()
    {
        return super.createProvisonalProject();
    }


    @Override
    protected IWizardContainer getContainer()
    {
        if (mainPage == null)
            return null;
        return mainPage.getWizard().getContainer();
    }
}
```

The stacktrace can be found [here](http://pastie.org/pastes/9664871/text).

The root of the issue seems that `ImageDescriptorRegistry` is created from the wrong thread because the corresponding `IRunnableWithProgress` runs [forked](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.6.1/org.eclipse.jdt/ui/3.6.1/org/eclipse/jdt/ui/wizards/NewJavaProjectWizardPageTwo.java?av=f#150). But I wonder why does it work for the normal `JavaProjectWizard` then? And the main question is: how to make it work for my wizard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a bug in `Display.checkDevice`.

Your call to `NewJavaProjectWizardPageTwo.performFinish` is running in a background thread, but the code is using `ImageDescriptorRegistry` which needs to be initialized on the User Interface thread.

This is intermittent because sometimes something else that you do will have already initialized the registry.

Comment: Good explanation of the reason and the irregularity.

Comment: I use methods `setErrorMessage(message)` and `setMessage(message, DialogPage.WARNING)` which load a warning/error icon. My read is this is the root of the issue.

Comment: But what I can't explain is the original eclipse wizard loads an error icon too, runs the finish operation forked and doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: My suggestion was wrong. Even if i omit the above mentioned methods I get an exception.

Comment: The normal `JavaProjectWizard` uses an image from the Java image registry in the wizard - this will have initialized the registry before the finish runs.

Comment: I have noticed that I get this exception if I run my wizard in the empty workspace for the first time, so the wizard probably tries to load an image for project folder. If I create another projects before running my wizard the exception doesn't appear.

Comment: @DannyLo my guess would be that `fBuildPathsBlock` `JavaCapabilityConfigurationPage#getBuildPathsBlock()` should not be null at that point in time. It should already be initialized.

Comment: I have implemented my own second page. I use it instead of `NewJavaProjectWizardPageTwo` and call `createProvisonalProject()` before `performFinish()` to create `BuildPathsBlock`. Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

`getContainer().run(true, true, runnable);` causes the runnable to be executed in a separate thread. The first parameter `fork` is responsible therefore. 
The call to `javaWizardPageTwo.performFinish()` atempts to access the UI thread and causes the invalid thread access exception.

If you set the `fork` parameter to false, the code will be executed on the current thread.

Why don't you call `javaWizardPageTwo.performFinish()` directly?

Comment: I built my code based on the original New JavaProject Wizard. The corresponding part is in [NewElementWizard](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.3/org.eclipse.jdt/ui/3.9.0/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/wizards/NewElementWizard.java#NewElementWizard.performFinish%28%29). There is `getContainer().run(canRunForked(), true, runnable);` and `canRunForked()` always returns true.

Comment: If I would call `javaWizardPageTwo.performFinish()` directly I hadn't possibility to use `IProgressMonitor`

Comment: your hint on how eclipse forkes threads was really helpful - please continue with providing further information in your next answer, that's really great!!!

Comment: @MartinFrank Thanks for your feedback, I'm glad the answer helped.